# updating database using AJAX in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

i have following code in controller

```
public function responcename(request $request) {
    $data = request()->all();
    //$name = $data['name'];
    $user = Auth::user();
    $userId = $user->email;
    /////DB::update('update users set tutorial_detail = ? where email =         ?',[$data['name'], $userId]);
    //$tutorial_name = DB::select('select tutorial_detail from users where id = ?', array($userId));
    return response()->json(['tutorialname' => $data['name']]);
 }
```

and route is

```
Route::get('change_tutorialname', 'teacher@edittutorialname');
Route::post('/change_tutorialname','teacher@responcename');
```

when i comment on $user = Auth::user();
                $userId = $user->email;
it works properly..
but when i uncomment it show error message from ajax
below is ajax code

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
$(".btn-submit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/change_tutorialname',
        data: {name: name},
        success:function(data){
            $("form").css("display", "none");
            alert(data.tutorialname);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("Record not deleted.")
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: what's the error you seeing?

Comment: alert("Record not deleted.") from AJAX

Comment: output the original message like: `error:  function(message){ alert(message) },`

Comment: or check laravel logs to see if it has any errors

Comment: ...or the network tab

Comment: YES IF I COMMENT ON BOTH LINE I SUCCESS

Comment: Uncomment both lines, then check the network tab of your browser. Tell us what you see.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
DB::update('update users set tutorial_detail = ? where email =         ?',[$data['name'], $userId]);
```

Try:

```
DB::statement('update users set tutorial_detail = ? where email =         ?',[$data['name'], $userId]);
```

Comment: when i use any variable or statement befor responce->json  ajax show error.. when i not use anything before that its success

Answer (score 0):

You cold try this:

```
    public function responcename(request $request) {
       User::find(Auth::id())->update([
         'name' => $request->name
       ]);

        return response()->json(['tutorialname' => $request->name]);
     }
```